# Ошибка "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, android

Вечер Добрый! Писал код по учебнику и тут ошибка - "Cannot resolve symbol". В чем проблема?

Даже код с офф. сайта сверил. Спасибо!

```
package ru.agava43.scmarket;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat =
            NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private static final NumberFormat percentFormat =
            NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

    private double billAmount = 0.0;
    private double percent = 0.15;
    private TextView amountTextView;
    private TextView percentTextView;
    private TextView tipTextView;
    private TextView totalTextView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        amountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
        percentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentTextView);
        tipTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipTextView);
        totalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalTextView);
        tipTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));
        totalTextView.setText(currencyFormat.format(0));
        EditText amountEditText =
                (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
        amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(amountEditTextWatcher);

        SeekBar percentSeekBar =
                (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.percentSeekBar);
        percentSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);
    }
}
```

[image: ОШИБКА]

Comment: а где пишет то хоть укажи)

Comment: Опс) Картинку добавил

Comment: Проблема в том, что используемые переменные не определены. Начинать программировать под android, не зная самых азов java – весьма плохая идея.

Comment: Ну и где у вас определен `amountEditTextWatcher`?

Comment: Если вас устроил мой ответ палец вверх и ответ принимашь как верным)в том случае если я смог помоч)и тебе в карму +100500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. У вас не обьявлена переменная `amountEditTextWatcher`
2. то же самое с этим seek bar

Думаю у вас есть уже EditText и SeekBar и предпологаю ыв хотите навесить слушатель на ниъ тогда сделйте так

1.

```
amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
```

2.

```
percentSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

    @Override       
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       

    @Override       
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        t1.setTextSize(progress);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(progress),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }       
});
```

На здоровье

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Бъянке главное стараться и быть внимательным тогда всё получится удачи в начинанияъ